# Python Script to pull data from Synchronous API vs Asynchronous API

Tags: python, database, synchronous

I'm new to scripting. Here is my question:

We have an existing Python script to pull data from an asynchronous API.The source team had upgraded to an synchronous API.When I provide the new API version (from v3 to v4), I get a generic error when I run the script. The only changer I made in the script was the URL.

> Error Message : "KeyError: 'jobId'".

It fails in this line `job_id = str(json.loads(job_id_req.text)["jobId"])` in below.

Here is my script:

```py
import json,requests,os,sys,zipfile,boto3
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta
from io import StringIO 

def upload_s3_file(ns_api_file,job_id,file_date):
    
    #ses_client = boto3.client('ses',region_name='us-east-1')
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    zip_file_location = cwd+'/'+job_id+'.zip'
    
    with open(zip_file_location, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(ns_api_file.content)
    
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_location, 'r')
    zip_file.extractall(cwd)
    zip_file.close()
    
    input_file = open(cwd+'/'+job_id+'.csv','r').readlines()
    open(cwd+'/extended_ns_api_'+file_date+'.csv' ,'w').writelines(input_file[4:-2])
    
    df_ns = pd.read_csv(cwd+'/extended_ns_api_'+file_date+'.csv')
    df_ns = df_ns.replace(',','', regex=True)
    

    if len(df_ns) > 0 :
        print('the rowcount of the file is {} uploading the file'.format(str(len(df_ns))))
        csv_buffer = StringIO()
        
        df_ns.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False)
        s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
        s3_resource.Object('bd-marcopolo-v1', 'ns_api/extended_ns_api_'+file_date+'.csv').put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
    else:
        print('send ses message for the zero file count')

def main():
    Headers = {   'Content-Type':'application/json'
                    , 'Username':'**'
                    , 'Password':'**'
                    , 'DeveloperToken':'***'
                  }
    post_url='https://searchapi.pubcenter.com/api/v4/report'
    fetch_file_url='https://searchapi.pubcenter.com/api/v4/reportjobs/{}'
    
   
    for index in range(2):
    #for file_date in date_list : 
        file_date = str(date.today()- timedelta(index+1))
        print('the api is call for date {}'.format(file_date))
        payload = {
                    'reportName':'Distribution PTQS Report',
                    'reportType':'DISTRIBUTIONPTQS',
                    'startDate':file_date,
                    'endDate':file_date,
                    'granularity':'Day',
                    'columns':[
                                'Date'
                               ,'PartnerCode'
                               ,'Adcountry'
                               ,'DeviceType'
                               ,'PTQS'
                               ,'ImpactScore'
                               ]
            }
        
        job_id_req = requests.post(url=post_url,data=json.dumps(payload),headers=Headers)
        
        print('url request status code is {}'.format(str(job_id_req.status_code)))
        
        job_id = str(json.loads(job_id_req.text)["jobId"])
        print('the job id for downloading the file is {}'.format(job_id))
                    
        if job_id_req.status_code == 200:
            while True:
                file_api_req = requests.get(fetch_file_url.format(job_id), headers=Headers)
                if file_api_req.status_code == 200:
                    ns_api_file = requests.get(url=json.loads(file_api_req.text)['downloadUrl'])
                    upload_s3_file(ns_api_file,job_id,file_date)
                    break
        else:
            print('the api call failed')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It seems that `job_id_req.text` doesn't contain what you expect. You should print it and compare it to the desired result. It may contain a helpful error message.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: first you should check what you have in `json.loads(job_id_req.text)` because it seems it doesn't have `job_id`. But maybe there is some error message or other information.